# Digital Representation in different forms of videos

Tags: architecture, representation

I need help understanding, using the idea of digital representation, what similarities and differences there are in videos shot by mobile phones, videos streamed online and the videos on DVD? 
What would you say is the basic representation strategy?

Kind Regards, Duldi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to really understand the basics, then you may need to start with understanding the different image formats like bmp, jpeg, png, etc(Start with bmp). 
These are basically image compression/decompression technique. If you want to get  deep into maths, then you may want to read some good book on image processing.

After you understand the image compression/decompression and, then you will appreciate the video format. That how the video which are essentially 25/20 frames per second corresponds to 2/30 images per seconds and how efficiently they are compressed.

And then try to read different video format/containers like mp4, mpeg1-4, x264, etc (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_file_format). And similarly if you want to understand completely, then read a good book on one of the video formats.

(Remember when you say video, the file also accompany audio most of the times, so you need a software to separate audio out.)

Once you understand the basics of formats, then you should pick your favorite and start debugging using FFMPEG. This is open source which implements virtually all the famous image/video formats.

Online streaming is nothing but sending these files on the network using network connection. And you may be interested in something called RTSP. Things get bit different depending upon you chose UDP or TCP. If you are using UDP, then you want to use good packetization technique well suited to the video format you are dealing with.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you it does help a lot, especially something to use as a frame of reference. From my understanding though there are very few differences in the ways videos are represented right?

Comment: I can't comment what you meant by few. But you may want to see the evolution of h26X formats from h261 till h264.